# Create a new model with a existing relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

So I have a model called `Issue`, this model has a relation called `IssueType`. 
A `Issue` has a `type_id`, which links them together.  
A `IssueType` has a `id` and a `name` which is unique.

The problem is when I want to create a Issue I want to send a request like this

```
POST https://server/issues
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "description": "just some random description",
  "type": "Generic"
}
```

So here the `type` is the `name` of the `IssueType`, when creating it.

How do I do this?

```
@Table(name = "issues")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Issue {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private IssueType type;
}
```

```
@Table(name = "issue_types")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class IssueType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column()
    private String name;
}
```

```
@RepositoryRestResource(
    collectionResourceRel = "issues",
    path = "issues",
    excerptProjection = IssueProjection.class
)
public interface IssueRepository extends JpaRepository<Issue, Long> {
}
```

```
@Projection( types = Issue.class)
public interface IssueProjection {
    Long getId();

    Double getLongitude();

    Double getLatitude();

    Integer getFloor();

    String getDescription();

    @Value("#{target.type.name}")
    String getType();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want here is what Spring Data Rest refers to as defining lookup types:

> Very often, domain models contain types that are value objects but
>   actually represent a particular value out of a dedicated set of
>   possible values. The Country class of the example above actually falls
>   into that category. Because we need to manage the super set of values,
>   there’s a repository in place. If it should be allowed to manage the
>   set via REST as well, the repository needs to be exported, too. As
>   repositories usually indicate an aggregate being managed, Spring Data
>   REST’s default way of handling that scenario would be to render links
>   to an association resource wherever a Country instance is encountered.
>   **The Hopper release train adds means to declare so called lookup types,
>   for which Spring Data REST then renders an individual property inlined
>   in the representation and also registers the according Jackson
>   Deserializer to make sure that that property value gets translated
>   back into an instance of that value type for PUT and POST requests.**

https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#lookup-types

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_customizing_item_resource_uris

So something like:

```
  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.withEntityLookup()
      .forRepository(IssueType.class)
      .withIdMapping(IssueType::name)
      .withLookup(IssueTypeRepository::findByName); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh this is really cool, it's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! :)

But damn that's a lot of magic happening behind the scenes

Comment: Hey Alan thanks for the answer. I experienced a problem with it, it does not use the validation when added in `IssueType`, how can I make it do that or use any validation for that field?

Comment: Ah my bad... I was stupid. Had to specify it on the relationship on Issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate object like `IssueDto` which will represent your JSON request like below:

```
@Data
public class IssueDto {
   private String type;
   private String description;
}
```

Then convert this object to your `Issue` and `IssueType` objects.

Comment: How do I register that this is the input object in the repository and where can I then convert it?